# How to get whether a layout or at least one of its child elements overflowed in android

Tags: android, css, android-layout, mobile

I need to implement same view of a page of my website to my android application. I almost created exact seen in my layout but there is only one thing i could not achieved yet. Since my webpage uses CSS, two div which use bootstrap grid system class like;

```
class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"
```

they automatically change the orientation and become row by row from col by col.

But in android i couldn't control this screen size manipulation. I assume that the best criteria is catching the overflowing of my LinearLayouts or at least one their childrens. And if i get this i thing i might be able to change their parents orientation for listing them row by row.

Samples;

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So is your web site loaded in webview or you are building native android app?

If it is all about 2nd case, you can use GridLayoutManager, which has a number of columns variable, which can be calculated at runtime.

You can init GridLayoutManager like this :

```
new GridLayoutManager(Context context, int columnsCount);
```

U can also create a function that calculates columnsCount depending on your screenSize/orientation/itemSize

Comment: I edited my answer little bit, do you need more help? @m3rt_ali

Comment: i will try and make feedback to you thanks for your attention : )

Answer (score 0):

you can use Google's flexbox layout library

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Sample:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_alignSelf="flex_end"
        />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```